# Visual Studio 2022 will not publish to existing Free Tier hosting plan

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, visual-studio-2022

I have an AspCoreNet project developed in Visual Studio 2022

I have an existing Free Tier hosting plan on my Azure account.

I am attempting to publish my app to a new App Service instance in my existing Hosting Plan.

When I run the Publish dialog from Visual Studio it finds my account, and I can select the Resource Group containing my existing Hosting Plan, but instead of allowing me to select my existing Hosting Plan and deploy a new App Service to it, instead Visual Studio shows me my resource group and gives me no options other than to create a new hosting plan. And since my one allowed Free Tier hosting plan already exists it only gives me the option to create a new paid for hosting plan.

Does anyone else have this problem?

Does anyone know how to fix this please?

[image: App Service Plan in Azure]

[image: Click Add new App Service]

[image: Where is my hosting plan]

Comment: my guess is the VS publish wizard doesn't support adding a new app service to an existing app service plan.

Comment: Well it looks as though it's intended to, otherwise what would be the point of the Hosting Plan dropdown if you can't choose an existing plan, only create a new one?

Comment: I understand your frustration...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, publishing from Visual Studio is not supported in the Free and Basic Tiers of App Service Plan with Linux OS. Is does seem to work with Windows plans.

Answer (score 0):

- I have created a sample ASP.Net Core 6.0 Web App in VS 2022
- Created New App Service plan (Free) and deployed the Application.

[image]

- Again I have created the new App service , I am able to see the already created (Existing Free) Hosting plan.

[image]

- I have tried with the different regions (for hosting plans) as well.
- Could you please cross check from your side once again.